# How to check all realm instances are closed or not

Tags: android, realm

I'm new to realm and trying to delete the entire realm database after logout. I want to check if any realm instances is running or not before deleting the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(config)](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#getGlobalInstanceCount-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-) to see how many threads there are open Realms on,

and you can use [Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(config)](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#getLocalInstanceCount-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-) to see how many local Realm instances are there open on this current thread.

If `globalInstance == 0` then no Realm is open on any thread.

Comment: Is there a way to  get the list of local instances? We have 2 instances that are left open, however none are coming from a Realm.getInstance() in our code !?

Comment: @3c71 i think you can only see the count